# Return the full array that include that specific element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a glossary component in React, that allows me to filter only the glossary terms that I need for a specific unit learning. I do have two different datas array, one for the glossary terms, and one for the units. This is my glossary data file:

```
 {
        id: 1,
      order: 1,
      term: "Mario",
      content: "It's a meeee"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
      order: 2,
      term: "Luigi",
      content: "Okie dokie!"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
      order: 3,
      term: "Peach",
      content: "Thank you, Mario!"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
      order: 4,
      term: "Bowser",
      content: "No one asks for a trap faster than a plumber!"
    },
    {
        id: 5,
      order: 5,
      term: "Ganondorf",
      content: "How dare you attempt to wound the Demon King!"
    }
```

This is my unit data file:

```
const units = [
    {
        order: 1,
        glossaryTermsRequired: [1,2,3]
    },
    {
        order: 2,
        glossaryTermsRequired: [4,5]
    }
]
```

Now this is my glossary component:

```
const Glossary = ({ glossaryId, glossaryTerm }) => {
    const [isOpen,setIsOpen]=useState(false)
   
    
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        insertGlossaryTerm()
    })
   
  return (
    <>
      <span onClick={()=>setIsOpen(true)} className="glossaryTerm">{glossaryTerm}</span>
      <Sidebar closeSidebar={()=>setIsOpen(false)} isOpen={isOpen}/>
    </>
  );
```

The glossary component take two props, the id and the term string. My aim is to click on the glossary and show those required terms in the sidebar that will open on click. Now for example, if I click on the Term Bowser, how can i get to show all the terms for that required unit?(4,5 unit 2)

THank you guys

Comment: I am not getting what's the logic behind. So if I click on "Bowser", the algorithm should understand that Bowser has id==4 , then find where that word occurs inside units array and extract those values?

Comment: exactly, if i click on Bowser i would like to see all the others glossary that are in that array, so (4,5 = Bowser and Ganondorf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Glossary = ({ glossaryId, glossaryTerm }) => {
const [isOpen,setIsOpen]=useState(false);
const [sidebarTerms, setSidebarTerms] = useState([]);
   
    
    
useEffect(()=>{
   if (isOpen)
     insertGlossaryTerm()
}, [isOpen])

const insertGlossaryTerm = () => {
  let unit = units.find(u => u.glossaryTermsRequired.indexOf(4)>=0);
  if (unit) {
    let termArray = unit.glossaryTermsRequired.map(id => elements[id].term);
    setSidebarTerms(termArray);
  }
}
   
return (
  <>
    <span onClick={()=>setIsOpen(true)} className="glossaryTerm">{glossaryTerm}</span>
    <Sidebar closeSidebar={()=>setIsOpen(false)} isOpen={isOpen} terms={sidebarTerms}/>
  </>
);
```

Explanation:

- a state to manage related terms has been created. It's a list of strings
- when `span` is clicked, the sidebar is opened
- useEffect is triggered as the `isOpen` state changes. Searches related terms and stores them in the related state
- state is connected with Sidebar so it received via props the related terms, ready to be displayed

To make it work you need to create a global object in my example called `elements`, that is a key-value JSON object where the key is the `id` of the element, and the value is the element itself.

Example:

```json
{
  '1': {
        id: 1,
        order: 1,
        term: "Mario",
        content: "It's a meeee"
     },
  '2': {
        id: 2,
        order: 2,
        term: "Luigi",
        content: "Okie dokie!"
     },
  ...
}
```

This avoids your application to loop through the whole list of elements to find those with the right id.

Then, you need to have `units` object visible too.

Improvements:

- you can trigger before the insertGlossaryTerm() than the isOpen() function
- if a terms can be in more than one unit, then you need to substitute .find function with a .filter

Comment: If you have used the find method, the units should be inside an array and not a json object right?

Comment: @Robozombie yes, both .find and .filter are functions of arrays. So units need to be an array of elements. In your case, elements are the unit objects you described in your question (so with `order` and `glossaryTermsRequired` keys)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm having an infinite loop inside the useEffect, even if you passed isOpen inside the array. I noticed that once I changed the indexOf with my glossaryID

Comment: so with 4 in the indexOf no problems, but if you pass the `glossaryId` params, there is the infinite loop going on? Pretty strange ... Can you post your code on a Fiddle?

Comment: Fixed, I had to parseInt the glossaryId that was a string Thanks for your help man, now works flawlessy